# A Story about humanity in a deadlocked nuclear war

Tags: story-identification, comics, time-travel, post-apocalyptic

Can't remember all of the details, but it was a comic book story about Earth in a future war having reached a stalemate and there was a time machine involved. I vividly recall the ending, which had a family out for a walk and they come upon a time machine sphere. When the father investigates it, he discovers two dead human babies inside it retro-aged by travelling from the aforementioned apocalyptic future.

Comment: Hey Damo, I've set a bounty on your question. Should you remember any more details, now is the time to come [edit] them in.